# Reading an array of chars from a binary file into another array of chars dynamically allocated in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, binaryfiles

I have a homework and I have to write an object into a binary file. Then I have to read that object from the binary file. Everything works fine,except a variable of type  char*. I read it, but at the end of the text i got some random characters. I think the problem is the string terminator /0 ,but i don't know how to handle it.
Can someone help me?

This is the code I used to write in the file:

```
        size_t n = strlen(input);// input is declared as char* input
        f.write((char*)&n, sizeof(n+1));
        f.write(input, n);
```

And this is how I tried to read this variable from the binary file:

```
        size_t n;
        f.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
        delete[] buffer;// buffer is also a char*
        buffer = new char[n];
        f.read(buffer, n);
```

I got the text from variable input, but at the end i got some random characters

Comment: `sizeof(n+1)` doesn't do what you think it does, but I dont think that relates to your problem

Comment: The variable was initialized with a text. My code is a lot bigger, I took only this part where I got a problem. @MooingDuck

Comment: `sizeof(n+1)` -- No need to read any further.  This is totally wrong.

Comment: `f.write((char*)&n, sizeof(n+1));`  you broke file by writing extra byte with unknown content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### C-strings *must* be nul-terminated

C-strings have *length* elements *plus* a terminating nul character. You do in fact write the nul to file, but you fail to allocate space for and read it from file. Make sure things match.

```
size_t n;
f.read( (char *)&n, sizeof n );
char * s = new char[n+1];
f.read( s, n+1 );
```

UPDATE: You have changed your code (as per commentary below) to *not* write the nul-terminator to file. Make sure to initialize it as such when you read it:

```
...
char * buffer = new char[n+1];
f.read( buffer, n );
buffer[n] = '\0';
```

#### Endianness nonsense you can totally ignore

As an aside, you are not considering endianness issues with your `size_t`. I would personally make functions specifically for reading and writing integers in a file-specific endianness.

```
size_t n = read_integer( f, 4 );
char * s = new char[n+1];
f.read( s, n+1 );
```

Supposing a little-endian file, we could have:

```
size_t read_integer( std::istream & f, int n )
{
  size_t result = 0;
  while (n--)
    result = (result << 8) | ((unsigned char)f.get() & 0xFF);
  return result;
}
```

A corresponding function to write a little-endian value:

```
std::ostream & write_integer( std::ostream & f, size_t n, size_t value )
{
  while (n--)
  {
    f.put( value & 0xFF );
    value >>= 8;
  }
  return f;
}
```

(Untested. I might have goofed something.)

Oh, also:

```
write_integer( f, 4, strlen(s) );
f.write( s, strlen(s)+1 );
```

Comment: I change the code like this and now it's working, but i want to see if it's correct like this `size_t n = strlen(input)+1;      // input is declared as char* input
  f.write((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
  f.write(input, n);`                                                                                                                       And for reading   `size_t n;
 f.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
 delete[] buffer;// buffer is also a char*
 buffer = new char[n];
 f.read(buffer, n);`

Comment: Yes... but... you then have the same problem you started with: a non-terminated C-string. Re-read the very first part of my answer.

Comment: ok, so i should initialize like this: `buffer=new char[n+1]` and in this way i will have enough space for the string terminator?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your help. I am sorry that I didn't understand your answear really well. I am still learning:))

Comment: Meh, this stuff is hard. It takes a bit of struggle to wrap your mind around it. Keep going! :O)

Comment: Thank you very much, I did as you said in the Update and everything works just fine!